# Why didn't the Founding Fathers foresee/prevent the Swamp I.e. the mega corp lobbyist govt complex system

Tags: constitution, antitrust

Why didn't the Founding Fathers foresee/prevent the Swamp I.e. the mega corp lobbyist govt complex system  military media financers Fed

Comment: Are you seriously asking why they could not foretell the future 200 years in advance? I know that there is some tendence to "divinize" them, but this is ridiculous. To put some examples, the presidential election system worked... until 1804, when it had to ammended, there were serious crisis in 1812 and 1833, and less than a century later there was a Civil War...

Comment: This seems incoherent.  To the extent that this question makes any sense, it may be worth pointing out that not much has changed.  Backroom deals, information asymmetry, war profiteering, etc., were all major phenomena back in those days; they didn't need to "_foresee_" such things because they already existed.  For example, many of the founding fathers opposed slavery, but none of them had the power to do anything about it.  They did not have the luxury of complete political dominance; their own political standings weren't that secure.

Comment: Off-topic voters, Re "*The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician*":  What exactly do you folks believe is being promoted or discredited?

Comment: [T]he mega corp lobbyist govt complex system military media financiers Fed conspiracy theory.

Comment: @agc - seconded. I can't tell what's being discredited here - I can legitimately argue for almost any target. Conservatism? (because the question might seem like an attack on originalism?) Progressivism? (because the line of questioning attacking lobbying - especially zeroed in on "mega corp" is an idea more likely to come out of OWS than AEI, but the clear answer is that the question is fallacious?) Big-L-Libertarianism (because some of this reads like Poe's Law type parody of people who question the Fed?). I'm gonna assume a good faith here, absent evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @Brythan, Re "*conspiracy theory*"... so you feel it's promoting the sort of [dumb disinformative theories](http://www.motherjones.com/politics/2018/01/putins-trolls-keep-targeting-john-mccain-and-other-gop-trump-critics/) promoted by people like the [Russian Troll Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_brigades).  I think this Q. could refer to, (or be *made* to), the less wildly theoretical [MICC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military%E2%80%93industrial_complex).   Perhaps we should remove the vague epithet-noun "*Swamp*".

Comment: I would argue that the founding fathers did exactly what you claim they didn't.  They gave people the vote.  They set term limits and balance of power.   Voters have all the tools they need to vote against lobby's and corporations, but voters don't always get it right.

Comment: @userLTK Term limits (at a Presidential level, at least, which I think are currently the only Federal term limits?) are a 20th Century innovation.

Comment: @owjburnham  You're right (and I knew that) - silly mistake on my part.  I still believe the constitution was written with the intent of trying to avoid such things in the future, like too much corporate, lobbyist or economic power, at least to an extent.

Comment: When the U.S. Constitution was established there was very little experience with democracy in the absence of a supervising monarch with real political power. Nobody foresaw how it would turn out, because there was so little precedent for governance in this manner. The French Revolution had not run its course, and most prior attempts at true Republics were tiny city-states or islands like Iceland, not sprawling federal nations. They looked a bit to Rome but that was 1250 years removed and had long periods of non-democratic rule.

Answer (score 4):

They did, in a way. **This is partly why they insisted on small, less-powered, federal government**.

Because the **only** practical way to prevent lobbying, is to eliminate the things for the government to be lobbied for. As long as you have a big, powerful, and money-rich government, lobbying is worth the effort and therefore basically inevitable, in some way, shape or form (the return on lobbying investment is always good).

Additionally, they explicitly made numerous references in debates, and provisions in law, to prevent the big perceived threat - lobbying by foreign governments.

As a side note, "mega corp" may sound like a nice populist slogan, but [AARP](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/clientsum.php?id=D000023726) is a major lobbying force that is the cause of one of the biggest (some would argue THE biggest) strategic issues facing US economy - the enormous fraction of US budget that is spent - and even bigger one projected to be spent next 30 years - on social support of retirees. Yet they are not a "mega corp".

Comment: This is on the right track, but could do with some references to the 'restrictions' on the Federal government in the Constitution, and how elastic they've become in the interim.

Comment: Re "*mega corp*":  *AARP*, a non-profit organization with 37 million members, it lobbies, but doesn't do things the typical megacorp does -- *i.e.* planned competitive plutomaniacal inebriety, while lobbying sufficient impunity for its next few benders/quarters.  Keeping with that idea, of megacorps as reckless rabelasian loot-drunk Gargantuas turning rivers yellow and whatnot, and comparing it to your stated dread of Leviathan.  Are these gargantuas dependent children who'll starve without their senior Leviathan, or a herd equivalent made bolder without a greater monster to eat them?